# What to do with repeated error "could not find function packageVersion" when importing dataset?

Tags: r, readxl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ojx.png)

I'm having a hard time importing my dataset on R. I'm trying to import my excel sheet but it keeps showing this error. Can I please get help on what's going on? I'm a beginner in R.

Comment: can you show what did you run to get this message?

Comment: Yes, I pretty much just clicked on "Import Dataset" when clicking on the excel sheet

Comment: I usually use one of these functions
readxl::read_xls()
readxl::read_xlsx()
depending on the excel file.
You can try and export the excel file to .csv within excel and then use read.csv() in R.

Comment: Please edit our question and provide more information! Are you using an IDE like RStudio? Do you want to import the excel sheet via GUI or do you want to directly type the necessary functions in your code? Of course, the latter is recommended.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.